# Select all data in sql with where condition?

Tags: java, sql

I have this query that I'm running in Java.

```
select book from com where genre=?;
```

I set the parameter for `genre` dynamically. Is there a way to sometimes set the parameter so that all data is selected?

Comment: `is that possible?` sure but you've got to let us know which DB you're using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual trick is to set a separate parameter for selecting everything:

```
SELECT book FROM com WHERE genre=? OR 1=?
```

When you set the second parameter to `0`, filtering by genre is used, but when you set it to `1`, everything is returned.

If you are willing to switch to using [*named JDBC parameters*](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2007/jw-04-jdbc.html), you could rewrite with one parameter, and use `null` to mean "select everything":

```
SELECT book FROM com WHERE genre=:genre_param OR :genre_param is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to be able to use the same script and pass in a parameter that ignores your "Where"?  Use this and pass in the string "AllData" to the second paramter to include all results and ignore your first parameter:

```
select book from com where (genre=? OR "AllData"=?);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a different query:

```
select book from com;
```

That will get the "book" column from all rows in "com".

Answer (score 0):

Just use a wildcard.
Ex. `SELECT book FROM com WHERE genre LIKE "%"+seachString+"%";`

Comment: unless this isn't allowed in the java implementation. Surprised nobody else has mentioned it if it is allowed.

Comment: This is certainly allowed, but it's a recipe for [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Also there is no indication in the question that what is expected is a wildcard search. If `genre='art'` should it really also return rows where `genre='fartbubbles'`? This query will do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE expression (SQL SQERVER):

```
select book from com where genre=CASE
          WHEN ? IS NOT NULL THEN ?
          ELSE genre
          END
```